# написать скрипт для вывода дерева

Tags: php

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать скрипт! есть бд, содержащая 3 столбца: id, id_parent, name
(1, 0, 'Телевизоры'),
(2, 0, 'Мультимедиа'),
(3, 1, 'ЖК телевизоры'),
(4, 1, 'Плазменные телевизоры'),
(5, 3, 'Диагональю до 45 дюймов'),
(6, 3, 'Диагональю более 40 дюймов'),
(7, 4, 'Диагональю до 45 дюймов'),
(8, 4, 'Диагональю более 40 дюймов'),
(9, 2, 'DVD-плееры'),
(10, 2, 'Blu-Ray плееры');
Нужно вывести сначала имена первого уровня как ссылки и рядом количество детей. При нажатии на них, с помощью метода гет нужно получать айди и выводить детей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что-то написал:

```
<?php
$cats = [];
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "beboss");
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM  groups");
mysqli_close($mysqli);  
while ($cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $cats[] = $cat;
      }


    function arrOfId($get_id, $cats,$fire = false){
      static $ids = [];
      static $idsParent = [];
        if($fire)
            {$ids = []; $idsParent = [];}
        foreach ($cats as $key => $value) {
            if($value['id'] == $get_id){
                $ids[] = $value['id'];
          $idsParent[] = $value['id_parent'];
                if($value['id_parent'] > 0){
                    $id = arrOfId($value['id_parent'],$cats);
                }
            }
        }

        return [$ids, $idsParent];
    }

    function getId($cats){
    $childIds = [];
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    foreach ($cats as $key => $value) {
      if($value['id_parent']==$id) array_push($childIds, $value['id']); 
    }
    $max_id = $childIds[0];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($childIds); $i++)
      if($max_id<$childIds[$i]) $max_id = $childIds[$i];
    return $max_id;
   }

     $get_id = getId($cats);
     [$ids, $idsParent] = arrOfId(@$get_id,$cats,true);
     $ids = array_reverse($ids);
     $idsParent = array_reverse($idsParent);
     $padding = 0;
     $test = -1;

     for($i = 0; $i<count($ids); $i++){
     foreach ($cats as $key => $value){
          if($value['id_parent']==$idsParent[$i]){
                if($test!=$value['id_parent'])
                {$padding+=20;$test=$value['id_parent'];}
                echo '<div style="padding-left:'.$padding.'px"><a href=first.php?id='.$value['id'].'>'.$value['name'].'</a></div>';



          }
       }
     }




   ?>
```

Comment: цикл в цикле подойдёт

Comment: не могу сделать, чтобы дети выходили прямо возле родителей. у меня получается, что сначала все родители, под ними дети сдвинутые влево и тд